# Polynomials modulo n

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $p,f,g,h$ be 4 irreducible polynomials with integer coefficients. Given that $fp \equiv gh \pmod{n}$ does that always mean (WLOG)  that $f \equiv g  \pmod{n}$ and $p \equiv h \pmod{n}$?

I feel like it's true because there's only one way to factor a polynomial but does it hold when taking it modulo $p$? and does it count as a proof?

Comment: It is easy to cook up counterexamples. Before I post one you need to tell us a bit more about your backround. For example. are you familiar with Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: yes indeed that what made me ask this question,

Comment: As $fp\equiv 0\bmod p$, it means $gh\equiv 0\mod p$, and as $p$ is supposed to be irreducible, it only means that one of $g,h$ is $\equiv 0\bmod p$. If further, $g$ and $h$ are irreducible, it only means $g=\pm p$, and similarly for $h$.

Comment: I just realized that I made a huge mistake it's $\pmod{n}$ and not $p$

Comment: I think the mistake was using $p$ to denote  both the modulus and a polynomial. I think it is a good idea to reserve $p$ for the modulus, for there is no unique factorization in $\Bbb{Z}_n[x]$ unless $n$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample. Let $n=2$ be the modulus. By Eisenstein's criterion $x^4+2$, $x^2+2$, $x^3+2$ and $x^3+6$ are all irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}$.
And
$$
(x^4+2)(x^2+2)\equiv x^6\equiv (x^3+2)(x^3+6)\pmod2.
$$
But the degrees of the polynomials already tell that $x^4+2$ is not congruent to either $x^3+2$ or $x^3+6$.

Comment: On the other hand, if the four polynomials are monic and remain irreducible after reduction modulo the prime $p$, then the uniqueness of factorization in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ makes the claim true. My counterexample is based on the interpretation that the polynomials are irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, but factor modulo $p$ in such a way that their products become congruent.

Comment: In other words, I posted this to check on such details that were not made crystal clear in the question. I will delete this, if the intention was to interpret the conditions in some other way.

Comment: thank you so much your comment was so helpful you can totally leave it

Comment: but why do we need the leading coefficient to be $1$ ?

Comment: @fedibenothmen We don't need that. I just normalize irreducible polynomials that way out of habit :-)